# How to make an instance between two edges?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I have found an effect that I wanted to make for a very long time. But I were not able to make an instance between two points of a mesh. Could someone please explain me how you can I do it. (I don't want the object in the middle, just the outer effect, thank you)
In the picture is the effect I want to achieve

[image: the edge effect]

Comment: Not clear what 'it' is. Can you provide an arrow, or something, pointing at the 'instance' and the '2 points'?

Comment: @RobinBetts: i just can guess, but i think the OP just wants a new vertex in the middle of an edge....

Comment: I want to make an instance between two vertices, in other words, I want to make an object, so that it scales and rotates depending on the location of two vertices making an edge. I kind of want to make an edge, but in geometry nodes (and i want to assign a separate shader but i think i could do that) @RobinBetts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to instantiate objects at the midpoints of an edge, taking over the length and rotation of the edge, the easiest way is to convert the mesh to curves.

This gives you the ability to take the rotation of those edges directly, and also derive the scale from the length of the spline.

This could look like this:

[image]

- First you split the edges so that they are available individually.
- Then you convert this mesh into curves and you get single splines.
- At this point you capture the length of these splines with `Capture Attribute`.
- Then you subdivide the individual splines so that you get the exact center point.
- With `Endpoint Selection` you create a selection for the midpoint, which you also capture with `Capture Attribute` for each individual spline.
- The node `Curve to Points` then converts these splines into points and gives you the necessary rotation.
- After instantiation you use `Scale Instances` to transfer the previously captured length of the spline as a scale. Note that I created the cube with a Z-length of $1$, so the spline length can be used directly as the scaling value. Your object to be instantiated must also have a length of $1$.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks complicated by i think i understand it (i was able to make it thank you)

Comment: @Levmorozenko You are welcome!